# What is best fit to use for theming variables or mixins in sass

Tags: css, design-patterns, sass, mixins

I am creating a UI library in which I want to provide the mechanism to theme all the UI components like **button**, **cards**, **slider** and all. I am confused between **variables** and **mixins**.

One way is to provide the no. of variables that user can update and based on that variables component classes will be derived. The same concept is used in the **materialzecss** library. And user will use like

```
//variables that are used to create component css classes
$primary : "blue";
$btn-primary :"green";
//then include the ui library
@import "_ui-variables";
@import "ui-library";
```

**_ui-variables.scss**

```
$primary : "red" !default;
$btn-primary: $primary !default;
// and other variables
```

and the **_btn.scss** will be like

```
.btn {
  // other rule sets
  color:$btn-primary;
}
```

Other way could be to use `mixins`. There will be a theme file for every component that will contain the theme mixin for that component and at the library level, there will be theme mixin that will include all the mixin of the individual component. As the **angular-material** has done

**_btn.scss**

```
@import "_btn-theme.scss";
.btn {
// some rules
}
```

**_btn-theme.scss**

```
@mixin btn-theme($theme) {
  // if user has added the btn-primary then use btn-primary otherwise primary
  @if map-has-key($theme,btn-primary) {
     $btn-primary : map-get($theme,primary);
  } @else {
      $btn-primary : map-get($theme,primary);
  }
  .btn {
     color:$btn-primary;
  }
}
```

and the **ui-library.scss**

```
@import "_btn.scss";
@import "_card.scss";

@mixin ui-theme($theme) {
  @include btn-theme($theme);
  @include card-theme($theme); // include all component theme

}
```

and the consumer will call this as

**consumer-theme.scss**

```
@import "ui-library";

$theme :(primary:"blue",accent:"yellow");

@include ui-theme($theme);
```

What are the pros and cons of these approaches? Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you can use CSS custom properties (CSS variables) that would be really easy. You would just need to add a class to the body change your all your variables at once. So you just need a default theme and then just some classes changing your theme.

I have a small example in one of my project, if you click on "invert theme" it will change the page theme to invert: https://vinceumo.github.io/atomic-bulldog-style-guide-demo/styleguide/section-organisms.html#kssref-organisms-accessibility-settings

The issue with CSS custom properties is that not every brother support it yet :/
https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables

Otherwise, I would highly recommend using sass maps. It is easier to maintain when you have few themes, and you can quickly generate your components using `@each` loop

For example, if you want to generate background color classes:

```
$color-themes: (
  primary:
    (
      base: #4c5c8c,
      dark: darken(#4c5c8c, 15%),
      light: lighten(#4c5c8c, 15%),
      transparent: transparentize(#4c5c8c, 0.5),
      contrast: #ffffff
    ),
  secondary:
    (
      base: #212529,
      dark: darken(#212529, 15%),
      light: lighten(#212529, 15%),
      transparent: transparentize(#212529, 0.5),
      contrast: #ffffff
    )
}

@each $name, $theme in $color-themes {
  .has-bg-#{$name} {
    background-color: map-get($name, base);
    color: map-get($name, contrast);
  }
}
```

So here we will get two new classes `.has-bg-primary`, `.has-bg-secondary`

If you add new entries to your map it will automatically generate new classes :)

I have created a Scss boilerplate using CSS custom properties (This one can be disabled) with Sass variables. It is optimized for themes creation. Most components are linked to variables (using map). Check it out https://github.com/vinceumo/atomic-bulldog

Answer (score 0):

Variables are going to be your initial best bet.

Creating a theme story isn't something you should rush through, but rather take the time to integrate solid, well thought variables for a base set of colors. After that, you can extend them with things like `lighten()`, `darken()`, and other tools built into SASS.

Then, use that base set of variables to establish component specific variables to scale the theme story as needed.